# How can I display culture-specific native digits instead of Arabic numerals?

Tags: c#, localization, formatting, cultureinfo

I want to convert a numeric value to a string, displaying culture-specific digits. For example, the Dari language used in Afghanistan (culture name "prs-AF") uses [Eastern-Arabic numerals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eastern_Arabic_numerals) instead of the [Arabic numerals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arabic_numerals) used in most Western cultures (`0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9`).

When examining the CultureInfo class built into the Framework, it lists the correct native digits (screenshot taken from output in LinqPad):

[image: linqpad output]

```
CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("prs-AF").NumberFormat.NativeDigits
```

However, when trying to convert a number to a string to display in that culture, I am not getting the native digits:

[image: linqpad output]

```
var number = 123.5;
var culture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("prs-AF");
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = culture;
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = culture;
var text = number.ToString(culture);
Console.WriteLine(text);
```

Can anyone tell me how to display the native digits?

Comment: Have you seen this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3055195/string-format-not-converting-integers-correctly-in-arabic/4781769#4781769 ?

Comment: `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = New CultureInfo("prs-AF");` ??

Comment: @Paul - I tried to use the answer suggested in that post but it didn't work. If you look at my screenshot above you can see that the default `DigitSubstitution` for the culture "prs-AF" is `NativeNational`.

Comment: As this is a popular question about `DigitSubstitution` property of `Cultures`, I'd like to refer to the useful article "[Bidirectional Features in WPF Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/bidirectional-features-in-wpf-overview?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8#number-substitution)" on this topic.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Digit substitution is something that takes place when you display *text* that contain digits.

It is not supposed to change the string representation of a number, as you've seen.

The number `123.5` is formatted as the string `123.5` no matter digit substitution. It is, however, *displayed* with the appropriate glyphs if `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture` is set accordingly and if the presentation engine supports digit substitution. (WPF do support it)

Comment: +1 and green-checked. Setting Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture causes the digit substitution to work. And while WPF supports this, GDI+ does not, which is why it was not displayed correctly in LINQPad (see the screenshots in the question).

Comment: +1 Great answer. Didn't know there's localization even on strings right before they are displayed.

Answer (score 3):

I looked at `NativeDigits` propety and the underlying field in Reflector and it doesn't seem to be used by anything when it comes to formatting (although `Used by` analysis in Reflector is not guaranteed to be 100% full). So it is possible that these values are there just for reference or something like that.

You can use your own `IFormatProvider` implementation by using the string output of `ToString(culture)` and manually replacing all digits by corresponding values from `NativeDigits` array. Although I'm afraid it's not the answer you were looking for..

Comment: I also used Reflector and discovered that formatting takes place in FormatDouble method of internal System.Number class. This method is marked with 'extern' that's why Reflector was unable to analyse its implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe what you need is this:

```
var number = 123.5;
var culture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("prs-AF");
var text = String.Format(culture, "{0}", number);
Console.WriteLine(text);
```

Comment: Six years later, this just writes "123,5", which is just the same problem the OP was trying to fix. The question is how to write this in the native digits.