# Formatting numerals and dates in other locales in C#/.NET

Tags: c#, .net, localization, digit

In an application I'm writing I want to display the current date and time, in English, but also in other locales.

For example Russian, Arabic and Chinese.

```
// DateTime.ToLongDateString doesn't support a IFormatProvider parameter
DateTime.Now.ToString("dddd, d MMMM, yyyy", new CultureInfo("en-US"));
// "Wednesday, 7 August, 2013"

DateTime.Now.ToString("dddd, d MMMM, yyyy 'r.'", new CultureInfo("ru-RU"));
// "среда, 7 августа, 2013 r."
```

Works fine...

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("dddd٫ d MMM٫ yyyy", new CultureInfo("ar"));
// "الأربعاء٬ 30 رمضان٬ 1434"
```

Seems to work fine.

*However...* I'd like to show the numerals as (Eastern) Arabic numerals, not as Latin/Arabic numerals. Though this could of course be solved by doing a simple substitution ('٠‎' to '0', 1 to '١' etc).

But then there's Chinese:

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy年M月d日dddd", new CultureInfo("zh-CN"))
// "2013年8月7日星期三"
```

[Chinese numerals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_numeral#Written_numbers) seem to be quite a bit more complex than just doing a simple substitution; sometimes one character becomes 2.
Next to that, The formatted date seems to show the current Gregorian date, not the [current Chinese date](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_calendar).

**So my question is:**

A) Is there any localization functionality in .NET/C# to display numbers (specificly dates) in other numeralsystems?

B) Can i force .NET/C# to display dates in the Chinese (and possibly Japanese and other) calendars, as it seems to do with the Arabic calendar?

Comment: `(new CultureInfo("zh-CN")).Calendar` is Gregorian, you may need a custom CultureInfo.

Comment: Number substitution works like this: (1) various `ToString` functions return standard (0-9) numbers; (2) when displaying the string in number substitution-enabled host (e.g., in a WPF window), the numbers are _displayed_ in a national script transparently for you (BUT the thread's culture must be set to the national one), see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6239729/276994); (3) this features works currently for Arabic, Hindi and Thai languages only, so no automatic way for Chinese classic numerals.

Answer (score 1):

Play with ToLongDateString()

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("zh-CN");
var myDate = DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString();
```

value for myDate: 2013年8月7日

Comment: Don't forget to save the previous culture and put it back afterwards, or strange things could start happening... :)

Answer (score 0):

See these questions (and answers):

- [String.Format not converting integers correctly in arabic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3055195/string-format-not-converting-integers-correctly-in-arabic)
- [How can I display culture-specific native digits instead of Arabic numerals?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6239729/how-can-i-display-culture-specific-native-digits-instead-of-arabic-numerals)
- MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.digitshapes.aspx

As to whether that will work with *all* languages? ...I wouldn't bet on it, especially in cultures like that of China where there are multiple ways and context-sensitive usage.

Comment: I can't seem to get this to work :(

`CultureInfo Arabic = new CultureInfo("ar");`
`Arabic.NumberFormat.DigitSubstitution = DigitShapes.NativeNational;`
`DateTime.Now.ToString("dddd٬ d MMM٬ yyyy", Arabic);`
`// "الأربعاء٬ 30 رمضان٬ 1434"`

strangly enough:
`string.Format(Arabic, "{0}", 1);`
`"1"`