# convert digits to arabic in @datetime.now function in mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, datetime, web

I am making Multilanguage website with English and Arabic. I have done culture switching using proper methods. Now I have @Datetime.now.tolongstring() function that display current date.Now in arabic version what I am getting is

08/ذو القعدة/1437

I want these number digits to be in arabic too how can i do that

Thanks

Comment: There is no `tolongstring` extension for DateTime, did you mean `ToLongDateString`?

Comment: I would remove `DateTime` from your implementations and have an interface over it. Then you can do the conversions needed in a "service" style rather than hardcoding them everywhere. This should follow your multilingual pattern better

Comment: Reopened - answers in [String.Format not converting integers correctly in arabic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3055195/string-format-not-converting-integers-correctly-in-arabic) don't seem to work in this scenario.